# Search for Files of a Specific Type

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and PyScriptor to create a script that I hope to use to first find a file of type (.shp) and then check to see if there is a matching file with the same name but with a (.prj) suffix.  I'm stuck in the first part.  I hope to share this script with others so I am trying to make the starting folder/directory a variable.  Here's my script so far:

```
# Import the operating and system modules.
import os, sys

def Main():
     # Retrieve the starting folder location.
     InFolder = sys.argv[1]
     #InFolder = "C:\\_LOCALdata\\junk"
     os.chdir(InFolder)
     print os.path.exists(Infolder)
     print InFolder

     # Begin reading the files and folders within the starting directory.
     for root, dirs, files in os.walk(InFolder):
         print os.path.exists(root)
         for file in files:
             print file
             if file.endswith(".py"):
                 print os.path.join(root, file)
             elif file.endswith(".xlsx"):
                 print os.path.join(root, file)
             elif file.endswith(".shp"):
                 print "Shapefile present."
             elif file.endswith(".txt"):
                 print "Text file present."
             else:
                 print "No Python, Excel or Text files present."
     return()

print "End of Script."
sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], r"C:\_LOCALdata\junk"]
    Main()
```

The only result I have gotten so far is:

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
End of Script.
Exit code:  0
>>>
```

Any suggestions?

Layne

Answer (score 0):

You're exiting your script before it even has a chance to get started!. Remove or indent these lines:

```
print "End of Script."
sys.exit(0)
```

Starting procedurally from the top (like python does), we:

1. Import libraries
2. Define the `Main` funcion.
3. Print a line, and immediately exit!

Your `__name__ == '__main__'` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man - duh.  Thanks for the input.  I did get it to work.  The code searches for shapefiles (.shp) and then looks for the matching projection file (.prj) and prints the shapefiles that do not have a projection file.  Here is the finished code:

```
# Import the operating and system modules.
import os, sys

def Main():
    # Retrieve the starting folder location.
    InFolder = sys.argv[1]

    text = (InFolder + "\\" + "NonProjected.txt")
    outFile = open(text, "w")
    # Begin reading the files and folders within the starting directory.
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(InFolder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".shp"):
                PRN = os.path.join(root,(str.rstrip(file,"shp") + "prj"))
                if os.path.exists(PRN):
                    pass
                else:
                    outFile.write((str(os.path.join(root,file))) + "\n")
                    print os.path.join(root,file)
            else:
                pass

    outFile.close()
    print
    print "End of Script."
    sys.exit(0)

    return()

 #================================================================================
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], r"G:\GVI2Hydro"]
     #sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], r"C:\_LOCALdata"]
     #sys.argv = [sys.argv[0], r"U:"]
     Main()
```